# Installing a source package from the web vs. locally

Tags: r

```
#doesn't work
install.packages(pkgs="http://courses.nus.edu.sg/course/psycwlm/internet/metaSEM/metaSEM_0.8-4.tar.gz", 
  repos="http://courses.nus.edu.sg/course/psycwlm/internet/metaSEM", type="source")

#but this works (on my MAC)
install.packages(pkgs="~/Dropbox/Rworkingdirectory/metaSEM_0.8-4.tar.gz", 
  repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Why?

Comment: it doesn't look like there's actually a repository at the URL you specified.  There is a set of instructions, but it doesn't indicate where you ought to be getting the tarball from.

Comment: @BenBolker
It's at the bottom of the page under:
[http://courses.nus.edu.sg/course/psycwlm/Internet/metaSEM/#sec-3](http://courses.nus.edu.sg/course/psycwlm/Internet/metaSEM/#sec-3)

Comment: I don't see anywhere on that page where it specifies the command you listed above.  I see that it says "*Download the source package of metaSEM. Run the following command (as Root) inside an R session:* `install.packages(pkgs="metaSEM_0.8-4.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")` -- but I don't see where it tells you where to download the source package ...

Comment: I'm trying change Mike Cheung's solution (post 3):[http://openmx.psyc.virginia.edu/thread/2358](http://openmx.psyc.virginia.edu/thread/2358) with installing it directly from the web instead of from my computer.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
library(devtools)
install_url("http://courses.nus.edu.sg/course/psycwlm/internet/metaSEM/metaSEM_0.8-4.tar.gz")
```

this doesn't work for me because I haven't installed the dependencies (e.g. `OpenMX`); you might have to do that part by hand.

Comment: I got the following error:
sh: /usr/bin/gnutar: No such file or directory
sh: /usr/bin/gnutar: No such file or directory
Error in system(cmd, intern = TRUE) : error in running command
In addition: Warning message:
In untar(src, exdir = target, compressed = "gzip") :
  ‘/usr/bin/gnutar -xf '/var/folders/j7/wj5lx6b96pjc2j9z34j72_380000gn/T//RtmplksNSG/metaSEM_0.8-4.tar.gz' -C '/var/folders/j7/wj5lx6b96pjc2j9z34j72_380000gn/T//RtmplksNSG/devtools5c56d4b87b2'’ returned error code 127

Comment: It looks like Apple removed "/usr/bin/gnutar in OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)."
https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/379

Comment: did you try the recommended fix there, http://day-to-day-stuff.blogspot.ca/2013/11/installing-gnutar-on-maverick.html ?

Comment: I didn't Erik van Oosten's solution seemed unnecessary. The package installs fine from the downloads folder.